# Callback for Facebook requestNewPublishPermissions - Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get publish permissions from my users in my Android app and I'm succeeding but when I get the permission I want a callback to tell me just that. Here is my code:

```
private void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
    Log.d("", "Requesting Publish Permissions...");
    if (session != null) {
        List<String> publishPermissions = Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "publish_stream");
        final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest reauthRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, publishPermissions).setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        reauthRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(reauthRequest);
    }
}
```

Does the `session.requestNewPublishPermissions(reauthRequest);` have a callback or something that tells me that the permission was accepted?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a callback for that request, but there's an easy way to get your desired result.

Just add a conditional to the `onSessionStateChanged()` callback. If you check for the permission in that method by using `session.getPermissions().contains("xxx")`, you should be able to check in there. Any time the session state changes, it'll call that method, and I think that includes updating permissions.

Comment: Hmmm... it could work but this requires the user to first hit publish and then accept the permissions and the click publish again to actually publish

Comment: Once the user accepts the publish permissions, it should be saved on their app settings on Facebook. From that point on, you shouldn't have to ask for permissions again unless the user removes a critical one manually.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I have tried getting current permissions in onSessionStateChanged() but even if user give publish permissions it does't included in session. So when i run session.getPermissions().contains("xxx") it return false. Any idea ??

Comment: Make sure you're running `Session.openActiveSession(...)` or a similar method to actually start the session. It should either pull a token from the cache or if the token is expired it'll get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add callbacks to your FB session.

```
Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(new StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
                    //do stuff


                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `StatusCallback` to your session.

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            switch (state) {
                case OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED:
                    // Returns here after you request publish permissions
                    // So call your publishing actions here
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implement `onActivityResult()` which glues things together.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```